# How can I delete images in Amazon AWS with cURL without using the SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$t=time()+60;
$to_sign = "DELETE\n\n\n$t\n/myimage.jpg";
$signature = base64_encode( hash_hmac('sha1', utf8_encode( $to_sign ) , $auth['secretKey'], true) ); 

$url = "https://mybucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/myimage.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=MYKEYNUMBERXXX&Signature=$signature&Expires=$t";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'DELETE');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Return error: `SignatureDoesNotMatch`

I'm trying to implement a simple function to delete images in AWS, without having to load the entire SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Canonicalized Resource in [Signature Version 2 Query String authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth)    is `/${bucket}/${key}`.

```
$to_sign = "DELETE\n\n\n$t\n/myimage.jpg"; # incorrect
$to_sign = "DELETE\n\n\n$t\n/mybucket/myimage.jpg"; # correct
```

Note also that you *may* need to make some url-escaped substitutions in your signature:

```
+ becomes %2B
/ becomes %2F
= becomes %3D
```

Note also that because you are using Signature V2, this code will only work in regions where S3 was deployed before Signature V4 became standard in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

```
deleteAWS4( "myBucket", "myimage.jpg");

function deleteAWS4( $bucket, $fileName ){ 
$auth['AccessKeyId'] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$auth['secretKey'] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";     
$region = "us-west-1"; 
$date = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." +0000";
    
$params = array();
$params['AWSAccessKeyId']   =   $auth['AccessKeyId'];
$params['SignatureMethod']  =   'hmac-sha1';  
$params['SignatureVersion'] =   '2';
$params['Timestamp']        =   $date;

uksort($params, 'strcmp'); $params_str = '';
foreach ($params as $key => $val){ 
  $params_str .= rawurlencode($key).'='.rawurlencode($val).'&'; 
}
$params_str = str_replace('%7E', '~',$params_str);  $params_str = substr($params_str, 0, -1);

$t=time()+60;
$to_sign = "DELETE\n\n\n$t\n/$fileName";
$signature = base64_encode( hash_hmac('sha1', utf8_encode( $to_sign ) , $auth['secretKey'], true) ); 
$url = "https://$bucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/$fileName?AWSAccessKeyId={$params['AWSAccessKeyId']}&Signature=$signature&Expires=$t";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, false);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $to_sign);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

// get the result 
$result = curl_exec($ch); // raw result
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
// turn the xml response into an array
$result = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($result)),true);

echo $url.'<br>';
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>";  print_r($info['request_header']); echo "</pre>";
}
```